# get location updates every 15 mins

Tags: flutter, geolocator, flutter-workmanager

I want to get updates on my location every 15 mins even when the phone sleeps and when the app is minimized. I am currently using workmanager and geolocator to get it but it doesn't work. It kept showing me that the location updates is stopped and disposed when I start

```
void main() async {
  _handleLocationPermission();
  await Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: true);
  runApp(MyApp());
}


Future<void> _getCurrentPosition() async {
  final hasPermission = await _handleLocationPermission();
  if (!hasPermission) return;
  await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
  ).then((Position position) {
    _currentPosition = position;
    print(_currentPosition);
  }).catchError((e) {
    debugPrint(e);
  });
}

@pragma(
    'vm:entry-point') // Mandatory if the App is obfuscated or using Flutter 3.1+
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    switch (task) {
      case simpleTaskKey:
        print('executed');
         _getCurrentPosition();
        print("${ScheduledTask.taskName} was executed. inputData = $inputData");
        break;
    }

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

I am calling this ScheduledTask in another file like this, `ScheduledTask.control();`.  When the user pressed on the button, it will start the timer using the workmanager.

```
  class ScheduledTask {
      static const String taskName = simpleTaskKey;
      static void control() {
        _getCurrentPosition();
        Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
            ScheduledTask.taskName, ScheduledTask.taskName,
            frequency: Duration(minutes: 15),
            existingWorkPolicy: ExistingWorkPolicy.append);
        // add your control here
      }
    }
```

When the interval is up, it shows a notification that the function has been executed but the location somehow is still not. In the debug console, it is showing this,

```
D/FlutterGeolocator(10382): Disposing Geolocator services
E/FlutterGeolocator(10382): Geolocator position updates stopped
D/FlutterGeolocator(10382): Stopping location service.
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(10382): Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=55a8af72-af00-4039-ad88-8fe07e46a58d, tags={ be.tramckrijte.workmanager.BackgroundWorker } ]
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(10382): Setting status to enqueued for b76febdc-ae5e-47b5-8294-3db31dc0e17a
W/FlutterJNI(10382): Tried to send a platform message response, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Response ID: 3
```

Is there something wrong with my code? I tried using StreamSubscription as well but it didnt work for me. Any guide?

Comment: have you added necessary permissions for background location in your manifest and info.plist?

Comment: Added these in android
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.START_FOREGROUND_SERVICES_FROM_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />`

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy package that may help you package name : `flutter_background_geolocation` you can find it on pub.dev .

here is an example how to use it :

```
import 'package:flutter_background_geolocation/flutter_background_geolocation.dart' as bg;

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ////
    // 1.  Listen to events (See docs for all 12 available events).
    //

    // Fired whenever a location is recorded
    bg.BackgroundGeolocation.onLocation((bg.Location location) {
      print('[location] - $location');
    });

    // Fired whenever the plugin changes motion-state (stationary->moving and vice-versa)
    bg.BackgroundGeolocation.onMotionChange((bg.Location location) {
      print('[motionchange] - $location');
    });

    // Fired whenever the state of location-services changes.  Always fired at boot
    bg.BackgroundGeolocation.onProviderChange((bg.ProviderChangeEvent event) {
      print('[providerchange] - $event');
    });

    ////
    // 2.  Configure the plugin
    //
    bg.BackgroundGeolocation.ready(bg.Config(
        desiredAccuracy: bg.Config.DESIRED_ACCURACY_HIGH,
        distanceFilter: 10.0,
        stopOnTerminate: false,
        startOnBoot: true,
        debug: true,
        logLevel: bg.Config.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE
    )).then((bg.State state) {
      if (!state.enabled) {
        ////
        // 3.  Start the plugin.
        //
        bg.BackgroundGeolocation.start();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That works when the app is open but when I minimized it, it doesn't work anymore. I have  added these permissions in my androidManifest.xml. Is there any other permissions that I should be adding so that I can get my updated location when I minimised my app?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.START_FOREGROUND_SERVICES_FROM_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: then I think you must use `flutter_background_service` in pub.dev and see if it works .

Comment: flutter_background_service with workmanager?

Comment: how can i implement it with workmanager? i ran the example code for flutter_background_service from pub dev but unsure how it works.. how do i make it give me updated location every 15 mins?

Comment: I updated my answer I hope that it helps you , if you have any more issues don't hesitate to ask .

Comment: I have used flutter_background_service. My issue was I didn't set the location permission to always allow. It is working now.

Comment: glade that it works for you , can you post your answer ? so any one that have the same issue can  find solution .

Comment: Sure. Added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

```
Future<void> onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  // Only available for flutter 3.0.0 and later
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });

    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }
  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });

  print('Flutter Background Service : ${DateTime.now()}');
}
  Future<void> initializeService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'my_foreground', // id
    'MY FOREGROUND SERVICE', // title
    description:
        'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.low, // importance must be at low or higher level
  );

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);


  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      // this will be executed when app is in foreground or background in separated isolate
      onStart: onStart,

      // auto start service
      autoStart: true,
      isForegroundMode: true,
      notificationChannelId: 'my_foreground',
      initialNotificationTitle: 'Supercare Services',
      initialNotificationContent: 'Fetching current location for checkout...',
      foregroundServiceNotificationId: 888,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      // auto start service
      autoStart: true,
      onBackground: onIosBackground,

      // this will be executed when app is in foreground in separated isolate
      onForeground: onStart,

      // you have to enable background fetch capability on xcode project
    ),
  );
  service.startService();
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<bool> onIosBackground(ServiceInstance service) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });
  return true;
}
```

> Remember to set your location permission to always allow if you want to fetch location in background.

In my case, I will need to request user to allow location permission to While Using. After that, you can request to "Always Allow" so that you can fetch location in background.

```
  var status = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.status;
  if (status.isGranted) { //if the status above is granted
    var status = await Permission.locationAlways.request(); //if granted, request to always allow
    if (status.isGranted) { //if always allow is granted
      await initializeService(); //start the background service
```

}
}